# How to prevent chrome extension JS from interfering with page JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am creating an extension which uses a variety of frameworks (backbone and handlebars). If the page I am loading the extension into already has these frameworks loaded then things break.

As an example, if the page my extension is loaded into already contains handlebars then my handlebars helpers get destroyed.

Logically, it makes sense why this happens - we have a classic namespace conflict on the window object.

Are there any well known approaches of overcoming this issues (other than ridiculous name changes?

Comment: Content scripts live in isolated worlds.  They can't see or interact with any javascript loaded by the page.  Could you explain how things are breaking in your case?

Comment: Maybe he is injecting scripts or relying on dom properties like a class being set.

Comment: Sure. My chrome extension loads handlebars as a content script. The page the extension runs in, already has handlebars and with helpers registered. As a result, these helpers are overridden by the extensions' handlebars. When I disable the extension all is well, and the helpers are accessible. I am also not injecting any scripts into the DOM.

Comment: Can you add your injection code?